# Shortcut way to select a range of columns and to addition to a vector

Tags: r, addition

I am doing a simple addition:

```
a <- data$a + data$b + data$c + data$d
```

However, I have a data set where there a 50 columns in the imported data and wondering if there is a short cut to select these, like:

```
data$a:data$z
```

And just add them up?

I know I can select a range by simple:

```
dataframe[11:60]
```

But then how to add them?

Edit:
A more concrete example

```
affect <- well_being_df$Affect1 + ... well_being_df$Affect50

affect
<labelled doubled>
[1] 21 23 43 8 10 ...
[38] 42 42 54 ...
[75] 23 14 42 23 ... etc
labels:
value    label
0 Not at all 
10 Completely
```

Comment: `sum(iris[1:4])` or maybe `rowSums(iris[1:4])`

Comment: I should add that the data is coming from a dataframe, tbl and are being stored in a class "labelled" vector.

Comment: @markus Yea but this gives me a total. Ill edit the post for more clarity.

Comment: Please share your data with `dput(well_being_df)` or if it is too large with `dput(head(well_being_df, 10))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your columns without "$" but still can use their labels :

```
rowSums(data[,c("a","b","c")]
```

If your columns are too much and u can't type "a b c d ... z", you can use ascii code of them with one loop :

```
vec <- rep(0,10)

for (i in 1:10)
{
   vec[i]<- intToUtf8(64+i)
}
```

It provides you "A", "B", ... ,"J" ; now u can use `rowSums(data[,vec])`

About your last question in your comment, when u use "," in data[] it defines row's index before it and column's index after it, also in data[] you can use a logical values, because of it above codes running correct.

Comment: What if I have 50 columns and 160 obersvations? rowSums(data[,c("a",......."z")]?

Comment: you can use the column index as well. ie: `rowSums(data[,11:60])` note the comma after the `[`

Comment: @see24 Thats it! Thank you! What is happening here in R for it to do that? What is the operation of the comma before the numbers?

Comment: @psych.tek ur welcome. I edited the answer check it and don't remember to accept and upvote my answer, tnx.

Comment: @psych.tek the comma doesn't actually make a difference in this case since you want all the rows in both cases. If you wanted to subset both rows and columns you would need it.